# How to force ffmpeg to refresh overlay image more often?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, png, overlay

I am trying to do sports live-streaming using ffmpeg. Score of a streaming match is being fetched from server and converted to png. This png must appear on top of the video.

ffmpeg allows to put an overlay over a video stream using image2 demuxer. If I use -loop1, this overlay updates approximately every 5 seconds. How can I force ffmpeg to read it from disk more often?

My current attempt with overlay updating once in 5 seconds(mp4 video for testing purposes):

```
nice -n -19 ffmpeg \
        -re -y \
        -i s.mp4 \
        -f image2 -loop 1 -i http://127.0.0.1:3000/img \
        -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay" \
        -threads 4 \
        -v 0 -f mpegts -preset ultrafast udp://127.0.0.1:23000 \
        &
```

P.S
I know, that I can make youtube streaming widget on the website and put score on top of it just using html/css/js. But unfortunately it must be done directly in the video stream.

P.P.S
I know, that I can use ffmpeg drawtext. But it is not what I want. I have specially designed png, which must be updated as frequently, as possible ( once in 1-2 seconds would be just great )

Answer (score 4):

Three things:

1) `-re` is applied per input, so ffmpeg is currently reading your image at a rate asynchronous with respect to the video. Since the video is being read in real time, the image reader queues the packets of the looped image till the filtergraph can consume them. So the updated image will consumed much later and with a greater timestamp assigned than when it was actually updated. Add `-re` before the image `-i` to correct this.

2) Skip `-loop 1` and use `-stream_loop -1` since the image2 demuxer can abort if the input is blocked or empty (due to update) when it's trying to read it. Although, since the input is read via a network protocol, this may not be an issue for you.

3) You've specified no encoder in the output options. Since the format is MPEG-TS, ffmpeg will choose `mpeg2video` with a default bitrate of 200 kbps. The `ultrafast` preset does not apply to this encoder. You probably want to add `-c:v libx264`.

Comment: Thank you @gyan ! new version takes image from filesystem, so stream_loop works good. But overall speed unfortunately remains the same(updates every 5 seconds). Code:

`nice -n -19 ffmpeg \
-re -y \ -i s.mp4 \
-f image2 -stream_loop -1 -re -i sets.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay" \
-threads 4 \
-v 0 -f mpegts -c:v libx264 -preset superfast udp://127.0.0.1:23000 \ &`

Comment: How often does sets.png change?

Comment: it changes every second

Comment: As confirmed by `stat -c`?

Comment: Didn't watch statc, but my script logs time after fwrite

Comment: Run with `-report` for a minute or so and share report.

Comment: added report to answer

Comment: Don't see the ffmpeg report. I see a stat -c log which shows update interval ranging from 1 sec to 3 secs.

Comment: Other link: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f3d79868b0d4e8c13228823a1f91210d20190429100705/dadaf3

Comment: Nearly the same speed. Ffmpeg report: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/78d13a29fd4f8374d49ad4c66d550d6120190429121122/b8f325

Comment: I am not a specialist in ffmpeg, so I don't really understand, on what stage the slow-down is happening. Maybe I should read/write my png file from/to RAM-fs partition directly?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192575/discussion-between-alex-fomin-and-gyan).

Answer (score 0):

I have found, that increasing framerate value of image2 to 90-100 makes file reading process faster, but audio becomes throttled